# Java - How to use HS256 with JwtAccessTokenConverter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, jjwt

I am currently following this tutorial on how to implement oauth2 Authentication and Authorization with microservices:

http://stytex.de/blog/2016/02/01/spring-cloud-security-with-oauth2/

I have it working as is, but I am having a real hard time trying to figure out how to implement jwt with HS256 rather than the current RSA256 algorithm that's being used.

I think I've narrowed it down to this snippet of code from the authentication server in the Oauth2Configuration class:

```
 @Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(jwtTokenEnhancer()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(jwtTokenEnhancer());
}




@Bean
protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
    KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"), "mySecretKey".toCharArray());
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("jwt"));

    return converter;
}
```

More specifically, I believe I'd have to change some things with the jwtTokenEnhancer method.

I've looked at documentation and I have not seen anything related to HS256 so any sort of clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are configuring your JwtAccessTokenConverter to use a key pair therefore it will use RSA. If you want to [setSigningKey](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtAccessTokenConverter.html#setSigningKey(java.lang.String)) it will use HMACSHA256.

Take a look at the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/225cb264f3fc1d364ceaf48ff71db62f72627cad/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtAccessTokenConverter.java#L163) :

```
public void setSigningKey(String key) {
    Assert.hasText(key);
    key = key.trim();

    this.signingKey = key;

    if (isPublic(key)) {
        signer = new RsaSigner(key);
        logger.info("Configured with RSA signing key");
    }
    else {
        // Assume it's a MAC key
        this.verifierKey = key;
        signer = new MacSigner(key);
    }
}
```

You can see if the format is not RSA then a MacSigner is used and [MacSigner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-jwt/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/jwt/crypto/sign/MacSigner.java) implements HMACSHA256

Comment: Yep. I looked right over that before just because I didn't know that MacSigner implemented it. Also, All I had to do to use it was to remove the converter.setKeyPair line. Thanks!